# tokenizer for keepwordfilterfactory in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, tokenize, solr4, filterfactory

I want to use the solr `keepwordfilterfactory` but not getting the appropriate tokenizer for that. Use case is, i have a string say `hi i am coming, bla-bla go out.` Now from the following string i want to keep the words like `hi i`, `coming,`,`bla-bla`etc. So what tokenizer to use with the filter factory so that i am able to get any such combination in facets. Tried different tokenizer but not getting the exact result. I am using `solr 4.0`. Is there any such tokenizer that tokenizes based on the keepwords used.

Comment: do you want "hi i" to be a single token or is it a typo? What tokenizers have you tried so far and what were the issues?

Comment: @jpountz : "hi i" is a single token and not a typo. There are some fixed set of words which can be single or multiple and needs to be tokenized based on these word list from a given string. I have tried the following tokenizer till now : `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory, solr.LetterTokenizerFactory, solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory, solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory, solr.StandardTokenizerFactory, solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory, solr.PatternTokenizerFactory`. The issue is if i have multiple words seperated by space i am not able to get it along with single word. I only get `bla-bla coming,` not `hi i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your 'rules' for tokenization (splitting long text into individual tokens). The example above seem to be implying that sometimes you have single word tokens and sometimes a multi-word ("hi i"). The multi-word case is problematic here, but you might be able to do it by combining [ShingleFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory) to give you multi-word tokens as well as the original ones and then you keep only the items you want.

I am not sure whether KeepWord filter deals correctly with multi-word strings. If it does not, you may want to have a special separator character during shingle process and then regex filter it back to space as the last step.

Comment: Basically i have a predefined fixed set of words which needs to be tokenized from a given string for a particular field and do the facets on these words only for that field. My problem is KeepWord filter works with most tokenizer till there is no whitespace between words and gives the expected output but the moment there is any whitespace i don't get that word. Like from the string in my question i get `coming,` and `bla-bla` but not `hi i`. So i need some mechanism that looks for defined words and don't tokenize between whitespace if it is multiword. KeepWord filter for multiword should work.

Comment: Try ShingleFilterFactory I mentioned after the Whitespace tokenizer and before your KeepWordFilterFactory. Check in Admin UI analysis screen (I a assuming Solr 4) what your text looks like when it goes through different stages.